# Not resetting cycle on multiple template render()

Tags: django, django-templates

I have made a tag that render a custom template based on the model type. I needed this because I wanted to show more detail than the `django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list` let me show for a single object, and I have multiple objects of different kinds. Here is the code:

The templatetags/extra.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def render_item_list(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, item_list = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires exactly one arguments" %     token.split_contents()[0]
    return RenderItemListNode(item_list)

class RenderItemListNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, item_list):
        self.item_list = template.Variable(item_list)

    def render(self, context):
        list_html = ''

        for item in self.item_list.resolve(context):
            context.update({'item':item})
            list_html += template.loader.get_template("list/%s_item.html" % item.__class__.__name__.lower()).render(context)

    return list_html

register.tag('render_item_list', render_item_list)
```

My problem is that the template uses a {{ cycle }} and the values are reset with every `render()` call.

I'm probably going to add to my own tag the cycle values, but I want to see if there is a better solution, like not resetting the cycle value across `render()` calls or even a different approach than this tag of mine.

More code:

`index.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load extra %}
{% block content %}
   {% render_item_list item_list %}
{% endblock %}
```

`object_item.html` snippet:

```
<div class="{{ cycle 'odd' 'even' }}" >
    ...
</div>
```

-- Edit:
Here is my new version of the tag, that can be used inside a for loop:

```
def render_item(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, item = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires exactly one argument" % token.split_contents()[0]
    return RenderItemNode(item)

class RenderItemNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = template.Variable(item)

    def render(self, context):
        item = self.item.resolve(context)
        return template.loader.get_template("list/%s_item.html" % item.__class__.__name__.lower()).render(template.Context({'item':item}))

register.tag('render_item', render_item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your object_item.html to look like this:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
<div class="{{ cycle 'odd' 'even' }}" >
    ...
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And then change the render() definition on your RenderItemListNode:

```
def render(self, context):
    item_list = self.item_list.resolve(context)
    list_html = template.loader.get_template("list/%s_item.html" % item.__class__.__name__.lower()).render({'item_list':item_list})
return list_html
```

Comment: I moved the <div> out of my object_item.html as you said, and I used the second form of the code as I showed. Can't believe I didn't think that by myself, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that the cycle tag works when it's inside a for loop - in your template, there isn't a for loop, so the cycle isn't updating.

If you want to use the cycle as it is, you could try rendering the entire list of objects in your template, and then have your template do a for loop over them - instead of doing a loop in your code.

Comment: I tried a different approach so that I could use my tag inside a for loop, did not work